# Finding last record in a day

Tags: sql, date

Please look at this result table, I want to retrieve last `Invoice_Number` of a `sales_rep` on `31-dec-2013`

```
INVOICE_NUMBER  INVOICE_DATE        FK_SALES_REP_ID
519740000010026 12/31/13 10:14 AM   121
518210000010868 12/31/13 7:34 AM    91
519740000010050 12/31/13 2:29 PM    121
519920000010273 12/31/13 10:25 AM   94
514990000010269 12/31/13 10:51 AM   127
514990000010270 12/31/13 11:09 AM   127
505700000012330 12/31/13 12:12 PM   106
518210000010867 12/31/13 7:24 AM    91
```

Result Table :

```
INVOICE_NUMBER  INVOICE_DATE        FK_SALES_REP_ID
518210000010868 12/31/13 7:34 AM    91
519920000010273 12/31/13 10:25 AM   94
519740000010050 12/31/13 2:29 PM    121
505700000012330 12/31/13 12:12 PM   106
514990000010270 12/31/13 11:09 AM   127
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you didn't specify your DBMS this is Standard SQL:

```
select *
from
 (
   select t.*,
      row_number()
      over (partition by FK_SALES_REP_ID 
            order by INVOICE_DATE desc) as rn
   from tab as t
   where cast(INVOICE_DATE as date) = '12/31/13'
 ) as dt
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Its working , for first value ?

Comment: Change the sort order to ascending :-)

Answer (score 0):

You're solution will probably look something like this. The important thing is to be sure to select the MAX(INVOICE_TIME) where the date is equal to the day you want.

```
SELECT * FROM Your.Table
WHERE 
    INVOICE_DATE = 
        (SELECT MAX(INVOICE_DATE) FROM Your.Table
         WHERE DATE(INVOICE_DATE) = '12/31/2013')
```

Comment: Pleas edit your question.